# Unable to click element in selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to scrape:

https://shop.mango.com/us/women/jackets-biker-jackets/leather-biker-jacket_53095011.html?c=CG&n=1&s=prendas_she.familia;16,304

My Selenium code clicks "discover my size" and then it enters height and weight clicks next button moves to next page. It then clicks belly shape and hip shape frame appears. It needs to click relevant span and then move to next. I am unable to click it using this code:

```
if "straighter" in str(df_temp['hshape']):
                print("here hshapeeeeeeeeee")
                xpath="/html/body/div[9]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/ul/li[1]/span/img"
                straighter = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath))).click()
```

similar to this is my code to click belly shape which works fine:

```
if "flatter" in str(df_temp['bshape']):
                xpath="/html/body/div[9]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/ul/li[1]/span"
                flatter = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath)))
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", flatter)
```

Doesn't throw any exception either. Just exits

Edit: Walkthrough:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried **other** code? What are you doing before you wait? `WebDriverWait` should be waiting for something you did... before? Maybe click something else? Your explanation is a bit poor, please be a bit more thorough: what does "keep moving" mean? What does "until there appears" mean? Last hint: debug, check what it is doing, it might be doing what you want without you noticing it.

Comment: What element are you looking for exactly? If you add some screenshots with pointers, we might be able to help out more.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quick solution, try:

```
xpath="//span/div[text()='Straighter']"
```

I'd advise to use xpath which does not depend on exact locations, yet identifies its target by specific element attributes. In this case, it would use the text of the element.

However, text is not always a reliable factor, especially not on multi-language websites. Alternatively, you could try something like:

```
xpath="//span[contains(@aria-label,'Hip Shape Selection button - Straighter')]"
```